# Appending html string to head in nextjs

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I am fetching data from API and it gives me an object with the property `head: '<title>dummy title<title>'`

When I call the HTML string in the head tag it doesn't show me anything. My code:

```
<Head>{data.head}</Head>
```

I also tried:

```
<Head>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.head }}></div>
</Head>
```

The code `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.head }}></div>` works in the body for me but it doesn't work in the head because div can't be called in the head. I also tried using Fragment instead of div but it isn't even working in the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly convert the string or object into tags, For your use case use can split the head object to get the specific title and use it.

[image: code]

Comment: I am not just getting a title tag. I am getting full metadata that I want to append to the head.

Have a look at this image:  https://i.imgur.com/xVikbUJ.png

Comment: then you need to add this by dangerouslySetInnerHTML only by using the script tag, not the div tag it will work fine

Comment: Like this? `<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />`